# SQL query construction

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I recently created a scoring system where the users are ordered by their points on descending basis. First I used to store ranks in a column of its own. I used to run this loop to update the rank:

```
$i = 1;
    $numberOfRows = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM sector0_players');
    $scoreboardquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sector0_players ORDER BY points DESC");
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($scoreboardquery)) || $i<=$numberOfRows){
        $scoreid = $row['id'];
        $mysql_qeury = mysql_query("UPDATE sector0_players SET scoreboard_rank = '$i' WHERE id = '$scoreid'");
    $i++;
    }
```

And it was really hard, not to mention slow to actually run this on a huge amount of users.
Instead, I tried to construct a query and ended up with this.

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT scoreboard_rank, id, points
FROM (
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS scoreboard_rank, id, points FROM sector0_players ORDER BY points DESC
)
as result WHERE id = '1';
```

But, this is just a select statement. Is there anyway I could get around it and change it so that it updates the table just as the loop does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using the following query :

```
set @rownum:=0;
update sector0_players set scoreboard_rank=@rownum:=@rownum+1 ORDER BY points DESC;
```

PHP code can be ,

```
mysql_query("set @rownum:=0;");
mysql_query("update sector0_players set scoreboard_rank=@rownum:=@rownum+1 ORDER BY points DESC;");
```

Comment: set @rownum:=0;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

update sector0_players set scoreboard_rank=@rownum:=@rownum+1 ORDER BY points DESC;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).<---This is the error I keep getting...

Comment: If you rerun the query again and again it would show that message. Try updating the scoreboard rank to zero and then run the query once.

Comment: This works perfectly! Can you please explain why did the ranks adjust because of this query. I need to be able to modify it in the future. :) *EDIT* is there a way to execute this right from PHP?

Comment: You got that message because mysql will update the table only if there are any changes.If not, it will not update the data. Suppose if the points got changed for a particular record, then this query will update some x number of rows and not all the rows , unless the change in points for a single record changes the whole ranking order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the RANK function .. I haven't actually executed the SQL, but it should work

```
UPDATE sector0_players
SET scoreboard_rank =
(
SELECT srank
FROM
(
    SELECT id,points, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points) AS srank
    FROM sector0_players T
) D
WHERE D.id = sector0_players.id
AND  D.points = sector0_players.points
)
```